# How to open ICS file from mail attachment in own app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I use the following manifest file:

```
 <intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />   
    <data android:mimeType="text/calendar" />
    <data android:pathPattern="\\*.ics" />
 </intent-filter>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER"/>
```

It supports to download the outlook calendar file in the android browser. But if i configure the email in the android it doesn't supports to open the attachment file from the mail. The Log cat Response for the Brower download is below

```
08-02 12:41:54.448: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///sdcard/download/Todaycheck.ics typ=text/calendar flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.GcalTest/.GoogleCalendarActivity }
08-02 12:41:54.518: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Start proc com.GcalTest for activity com.GcalTest/.GoogleCalendarActivity: pid=3326 uid=10024 gids={3003, 1015}
```

If i open from the email configuration Logcat:

```
08-02 12:44:57.848: INFO/NotificationService(53): enqueueToast pkg=com.android.email callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@43ce7e28 duration=0
08-02 12:44:57.908: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/11/RAW flg=0x1 }
08-02 12:44:57.968: INFO/NotificationService(53): enqueueToast pkg=com.android.email callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@43cfdc88 duration=0
08-02 12:44:57.999: WARN/InputManagerService(53): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43d21a48
```

How to open ics file in the Email Configuration in android?
 Can any one help me to solve this?

**Note**: If I use `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />` I can able to open the ics file in Email canfiguration. But it supports to open all the file format to open from my application. I need to open ics file only.

Comment: SRS what do you mean with email configuration?

Comment: Default email configuration in the Android2.1 emulator.(Like as a outlook )